# How to use UPDATE command in spark-sql & DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sql-update, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to implement `UPDATE` command on `DataFrames` in spark. But getting this error. Please put suggestions on what should be done.

```
17/01/19 11:49:39 INFO Replace$: query --> UPDATE temp SET c2 = REPLACE(c2,"i","a");
17/01/19 11:49:39 ERROR Main$: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier UPDATE found

UPDATE temp SET c2 = REPLACE(c2,"i","a");
^
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier UPDATE found

UPDATE temp SET c2 = REPLACE(c2,"i","a");
```

This is the program

```
object Replace extends SparkPipelineJob{
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
  protected implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats

  def createSetCondition(colTypeMap:List[(String,DataType)], pattern:String, replacement:String):String = {
    val res = colTypeMap map {
      case (c,t) =>
        if(t == StringType)
          c+" = REPLACE(" + c + ",\"" + pattern + "\",\"" + replacement + "\")"
        else
          c+" = REPLACE(" + c + "," + pattern + "," + replacement + ")"
    }
    return res.mkString(" , ")
  }

  override def execute(dataFrames: List[DataFrame], sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext, params: String, productId: Int) : List[DataFrame] = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val replaceData = ((parse(params)).extractOpt[ReplaceDataSchema]).get
    logger.info(s"Replace-replaceData --> ${replaceData}")

    val (inputDf, (columnsMap, colTypeMap)) = (dataFrames(0), LoadInput.colMaps(dataFrames(0)))

    val tableName = Constants.TEMP_TABLE
    inputDf.registerTempTable(tableName)

    val colMap = replaceData.colName map {
      x => (x,colTypeMap.get(x).get)
    }
    logger.info(s"colMap --> ${colMap}")

    val setCondition = createSetCondition(colMap,replaceData.input,replaceData.output)
    val query = "UPDATE "+tableName+" SET "+setCondition+";"
    logger.info(s"query --> ${query}")

    val outputDf = sqlContext.sql(query)
    List(outputDf)
  }
}
```

Here is some extra information.

```
17/01/19 11:49:39 INFO Replace$: Replace-replaceData --> ReplaceDataSchema(List(SchemaDetectData(s3n://fakepath/data37.csv,None,None)),List(c2),i,a)
17/01/19 11:49:39 INFO Replace$: colMap --> List((c2,StringType))
```

data37.csv

```
c1 c2
90 nine
```

Please ask for extra information if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Spark SQL doesn't support `UPDATE` queries. If you want to "modify" the data you should create new table with `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *  REPLACE(c2, 'i', 'a') AS c2 FROM table
```